# Best practice to "transport" trained model from sklearn

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, sklearn-pandas

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model


# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Train the model using the training sets
regr.fit(X_train, y_train)
# how save ?????
# save here
```

What the **best practice** to *save* the *trained model* and use in other place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sklearn` has a `joblib` module for persisting models and/or saving to a file:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib

joblib.dump(regr, 'file_name.pkl')

# load pickled model later
regr = joblib.load('file_name.pkl')
```

You can also use Python's builtin `pickle` but the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#persistence-example) recommend to use `joblib` for efficiently pickling objects with large `numpy` arrays

Comment: Is this a pickle file type ?

Comment: Similar to, but you probably can't deserialize with `pickle` if you serialized with `joblib`.